# How to have different input text styles in same html form?

Tags: html, css, forms, textinput

I would like to show a form with submit button, to post the texts fields back to server with:

- a text input called `title`, with border
- text called `chapter` and `section` no border, and their should be assigned in JavaScript

I want chapter/section not modifiable and short.  But Title is a normal input and should be very close to the word Title, like:

```
Chapter 3 Section 4 
       _____________
Title |_____________|
```

I wrote CSS like `"input[type="notext"]{border: none}` then either both text inputs have border, or none has border.  I basically want the two inputs to have different style, or some other kind of field for chapter/section for me to set value is fine too.  So how to achieve this? Don't need to be compatible for IE8 and before.

```css
input[type="text"]{
border: none;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Chapter<input type="text" value="3" name="cha_n" readonly/></td>
            <td>Section <input type="text" value="4" name="sec"     readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title  </td>
            <td><input type="text" style="inputtext" name="title" id="title"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td span='2'><a id="submit" href="javascript: check()">Send</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a CSS class for your inputs and just use them.

For inputs with class example:

```
input.example {
        border: none;
        font-size: 16px;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<input class="example" type="text" value="3" name="cha_n" readonly/>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/x762v24a/

---

A less generic way to achieve this is to use CSS attribute selector:

```
input[name="cha_n"] {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so is there a way to minimize the chapter input box to just enough, since the value is a readonly already set?

Comment: Yes, there is, but the style can't change dynamically just via CSS, you would have to use script, if that's ok

Comment: You can use the size attribute of inputs to adjust their size too if you know what range of values you will be dealing with

Answer (score 1):

To remove the borders on the chapter and section inputs, use:

```css
input[readonly] {
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Chapter<input type="text" value="3" name="cha_n" readonly/></td>
            <td>Section <input type="text" value="4" name="sec"     readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title  </td>
            <td><input type="text" style="inputtext" name="title" id="title"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td span='2'><a id="submit" href="javascript: check()">Send</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give inputs having the same style an 'class' attribute,then :

```
.style1
{
    border = 0px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.style2
{
    margin = 0px;
    padding = 0px;
    border = 1px;
}
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Chapter<input type="text" value="3" name="cha_n" class="style1" readonly/></td>
        <td>Section <input type="text" value="4" name="sec"  class="style1"   readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title  </td>
        <td><input type="text" style="inputtext" class="style2" name="title"id="title"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td span='2'><a id="submit" href="javascript: check()">Send</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I put in the fiddle and it didn't work like you said?

Comment: Your CSS syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Chapter<input type="text" value="3" name="cha_n" /></td>
            <td>Section <input type="text" value="4" name="sec" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="border:none;font-size:14px;" name="title"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td span='2'><a id="submit" href="javascript: check()">Send</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```